# Make "Reset Page Content" honor audience targetting?

Tags: 2010, audience-targeting, bug

**Question:**

How can I prevent "Reset Page Content" from showing audience-targetted web parts to users which are not a member of that audience?

**Details:**

I have seven shared web parts on a personalizable page. Some are targetted to one a first audience, others to a second.

When any user uses the "Reset Page Content" command (from the Welcome Menu), they see all web parts, regardless of audience. Refreshing the page after all web parts are visible shows only the correctly audience-targetted web parts.

Repro steps:

1. Place shared web parts on the page, targetted across two audiences
2. Personalize the page as a user in only one of the audiences
3. Use the "Reset Page Content" command as same user
4. Observe that all web parts, regardless of audience targetting, appear on your page
5. Refresh your page
6. Observe that web parts targetted to *other audiences* do not appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Robert R. Freeman for his [Personalization and Audience Targeting Reset Page Content Bug](http://rrfreeman.blogspot.com/2009/09/personalization-and-audience-targeting.html) article, which provided a suitable "solution" for my problem.